# Port forwarding through VPN for NAT penetration

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

**Problem:**

- I want **Service1 listening on port XXXX** hosted on my **local windows 10 machine** to be accessible to public, but my local machine is behind ISP NAT.
- I have a **Remote Sever** with static public IP

**Question:**

What should be configured on those nodes:

Public Client-->Remote Server-->VPN tunnel-->Local Router-->Local Machine-->Local Service

**Progress:**

I have done something similar successfully with another Service, let's call it **Service2** with port **YYYY**:

- Port YYYY is open on **Remote Server**.
- On **Remote Server**, Port YYYY is forwarded to **Local Router**'s VPN client IP address.
- On **Local Router**, traffic with DSCP tag XX is policy routed to VPN interface.
- On **Local Machine**, Service2 is DSCP tagged XX.

However, Service2 only uses UDP, while Service1 uses both TCP and UDP, and for some reason, DSCP tag does not work on TCP on Local Machine.

For **Service1**:

- Port XXXX is open on **Remote Server**.
- On **Remote Server**, Port XXXX is forwarded to **Local Router**'s VPN client IP address.
- On **Local Router**, traffic with "**local port**" of XXXX is policy routed to VPN interface.

**Have I done this correctly ?**